# Turn off a VBScript program while it is running

Tags: vbscript, message

*(This is a .vbs program)* I am trying to make a message bot for a program but I came up with a problem where if you set the time for too long, and set number of messages too high, you can't stop the program easily and have to deal with your message being typed over and over again until it is finished. Is there a way to add an option while it is running to stop the message from being typed?
    Here is the code:

```
set shell = createobject ("wscript.shell")

strtext = inputbox ("Type the message you like to type")
strtimes = inputbox ("How many times would you like to type this message?")
strspeed = inputbox ("How fast do you like to message? (1000 = one per sec, 100 = 10 per sec etc)")
strtimeneed = inputbox ("How many SECONDS do you need to get to your input box?")
If not isnumeric (strtimes & strspeed & strtimeneed) then
msgbox "You entered something else then a number on Times, Speed and/or Time need. Closing program"
wscript.quit
End If
strtimeneed2 = strtimeneed * 1000
do
msgbox "You have " & strtimeneed & " seconds to get to your input area where you are going to message."
wscript.sleep strtimeneed2
shell.sendkeys ("Hello" & "{enter}")
for i=0 to strtimes
shell.sendkeys (strtext & "{enter}")
wscript.sleep strspeed
Next
shell.sendkeys ("Bye" & "{enter}")
wscript.sleep strspeed * strtimes / 10
returnvalue=MsgBox ("Want to send the messages again with the same info?",36)
If returnvalue=6 Then
Msgbox "Ok Messagebot will activate again"
End If
If returnvalue=7 Then
msgbox "Messaging is shutting down"
wscript.quit
End IF
loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set up a shortcut to terminate all running `wscript.exe` processes. Click right mouse button on the desktop, in context menu choose New - Shortcut:

[image: context menu - New - Shortcut]

Enter `%comspec% /c taskkill /f /im wscript.exe` as location and click <kbd>Next</kbd>:

[image: location]

Enter a name you like and click <kbd>Finish</kbd>:

[image: name]

Also you may assign hot keys in shortcut properties.

Comment: This really helped, I appreciate the help